# Entity Framework detects model modification although db is updated with SQL Compare

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sqlcompare

I'm using Red Gate SQL Compare to upgrade my database without losing data. I also use ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework and SQL Server.

Problem is that Visual Studio still detects model modification although I've already updated the database with Red Gate SQL Compare. When I try to run `add-migration` in Visual Studio and then `update-database`, it crashes saying that the fields already exists.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you not upgrading your database using a migration?

Comment: The migrations table is still based on the old model. EF compares it to a checksum of the new model. So: if you routinely want to upgrade the database manually, switch off migrations.

Comment: I cannot use migrations because the database is on a production server without visual studio installed. And i actually did switch off the migrations (By deleting the migrations folder right?).

Answer (score 1):

You may delete generated migration that is crashing, then run Add-Migration command once again, but with -IgnoreChanges flag. It will generate empty migration that will effectively do nothing except adding new entry into migration table with  current model info. This should help you go on with your explicit db update.